# Electron: How can I request an image from a url and return to renderer process?

Tags: node.js, image, http, electron, frontend

Could anyone tell me how to get an image with electron net.request ? My trial following return some unknown encoding data, and when I return it to "src" attribute of a "img" tag in the renderer process, I can not get an image showing.

```
let netInfo = {}
netInfo.host = "***"
netInfo.protocol = "***"
netInfo.method = 'GET'
netInfo.path = "***"

const request = net.request(netInfo)

request.on('response', (response) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)

        let replyData = {}
        replyData.apiName = 'get-verify-code-image'
        replyData.status = 'SUCCESS'

        replyData.data = `${chunk}`

        e.reply('api-request-reply', replyData)
        return
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
})
```

What I get from server is like this:

```
src="�PNG


IHDRP(i`}�IDATx��YohE_ܽKP)�H���EDTD��R�"*ED ZT����?�PB�BP(����?T%�����I+��
j)J�5���Pù�|ovvovo�v�v��!�v���ߛ���5�RJ)��RJ)�<�����,��d��k  V�
�yX��>e�5�^tZ��&xv։��   ]hS�����&��Þ��죊K�7Ż̘.�o:�   c'��X�ˣ��&~h�n��-�ܡյ�1h�d^�ˡg�gs9�;�t�*�[���.{~�9��"l���Ki֍C�#�z��*.q��p�ᤁS�O�m�y��bq�QQl030J��׽�[D8$�a%������|�8E�C��'Ê�+��^���lz�!�%{��lq�ϡ_%
��b����
#�5�"� O�ö#h�{�,����5+rR־(xPȊ�c7xx�a���Ne���%{���H�]�37���КV^�[r~����Bo.�Z��<���HW��^�oOk-��//;%��v���uwL��� 2ؗX��B"�U7���5٢I�GÓ���&����(]D���2���2|r�B��4�Ӏ�+�ѩ(@LЕŐ�� �I��qU�2����Ꮡ�Ί?�$�*�2{%��@2W�Blӕ&V}]5E��s�P���C)�GU$�P����OA�޽@!=I�[U�ݤb�|ޱ�O�ߣ_��_`���Dx�vM&�������p�t�E�oj��6�,����]�%�w�h�gxH�.7�&�<�=�P��(��[-�}�1v�q@��f���{+�����98�c�+������9��c�b�o���r��j�`��O_�}�+0`V]%�]�
��]Uuȫ���"�(�.ځ�T�G��]R�!}�Ӟ�M�"�T���y/���I�]�!����g���z�
rQ����cA��vRy��S9�^��1k'"�ۃa�τ��0{K)��g���������\]�e�͚  O+��'#b��D��RE+��"����SB�Ґ�uJ#�8ӭmn�`X�̠�4��/�w���RoNlԩ������1�R�Ι�T#��<�%B�:JoT�����zg�&�h$N�x�~Í�'xRi�*���*�  x��[�6�#V��E$ ��3j�s4ڣ{��Uh��sS�t{a��e��Сo(�%��p�J�a5!L�u"�Y?]y��   '�q_����jȲf����Ů��-g4`�W޴Ӗq
��k� >��8�����3�g!UJ��T]r3�3�7U,x��;�+pE�����(��w,{�������Ԇl��_Ӗ?a�ݻ���1��$�"����W
(����I�bt)�ݦ�,
r��HA0w��
�p�ƂRԣ ]�~�:��X��r?t��w�[
�]*%)��"ĿK�K��H]*걿NХ�ʜ�3� �r�ʿ��\6���IEND�B`�"
```

Comment: You might want to look into [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), using which you can set the `src` attribute to the image data (not the raw data though, but encoded -- most probably using Base64). Could that be what you're looking for? The value of the `src` attribute has to be an URL in any case; simply setting it to the raw image data **won't** work (as you've seen).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I added data url headers like, data: image/png;base64,..., but it is still not working.

Comment: Well, that's probably because the data isn't Base64. It's the raw image data. Take a closer look at the documentation.

Comment: To turn the data into Base64 you can use `window.btoa(`